# React TypeScript: Preventing component restart when switching tabs in app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components, state

I'm developing a React TypeScript application where I've implemented tabbed content, similar to a browser. Each tab contains a component, and I've encountered an issue where switching tabs causes the components to restart, leading to loss of data in forms, open modals, etc. These components are stored in a list of objects. How can I ensure that switching tabs doesn't cause the component to restart, thus preserving the data within it?

---

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Initially, I stored the components directly in an array of objects and rendered them based on the active tab index.
- I also experimented with React Router and conditional rendering, but couldn't prevent the component from reinitializing when switching tabs.

```js
interface MainContentTab {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  content: JSX.Element;
  history: JSX.Element[];
  icon?: JSX.Element;
  state?: any;
}
```

```js
...

export const useTabs = () => {
  return useContext(TabsContext);
};

export const TabsProvider = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
  const [tabs, setTabs] = useState<MainContentTab[]>([]);
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState<string>("");
  ...
  return (
    <TabsContext.Provider value={{ tabs, addTab, ... }}> {children} </TabsContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

```js
const MainContentTabs = () => {
  return (<>
    <Box
      component="main"
      className="MainContent"
      ... />
      {/* solution proposed from Alex Wayne, 
          it works but I really want to save the state, 
          maby for refreshing the site? */}
      {tabs.map((tab, index) => (
        <Box sx={{ display: (tab.id === activeTab) ? "block" : "none" }}>
          {tab.content || null} 
        </Box>
      ))}
        
      {/* Old solution */}
      {/* {tabs.find(tab => tab.id === activeTab)?.content || null} */}
    </Box> 

    {contextMenuPos && (
      <TabsContextMenu 
        tabId={contextMenuTabId} 
        x={contextMenuPos.x} 
        y={contextMenuPos.y} 
        onClose={handleCloseContextMenu} />
    )} 
  </>);
};
```

This image shows the old solution, but I want a more solution that saves the component render status:
[image]

What I was expecting:

- I expected the components to retain their state and not reinitialize when switching tabs, similar to how browsers preserve the state of opened tabs.

Comment: Where's the code where you render the selected tab? That's likely where the issue is.

Comment: I really forgot it, but now i edited my first post and add it in it

Answer (score 1):

If a component is no longer being rendered, it will be destroyed. And if you then render it again, it will be recreated.

So you are rendering tabs like this:

```
{ selectedTab === 'a' && <MyTabA /> }
{ selectedTab === 'b' && <MyTabB /> }
```

Then when `selectedTab` becomes `'a'`, the `<MyTabA />` component is created and rendered. When it becomes `'b'`, the component and all its state are destroyed.

---

So instead, you want to render *all* your tabs, but just hide them being displayed.

```
<div style={{ display: selectedTab === 'a' ? 'block' : 'none'><MyTabA /></div>
<div style={{ display: selectedTab === 'b' ? 'block' : 'none'><MyTabB /></div>
```

Now they all exist at the same time and are all *rendered* simultaneously, but you are only *showing* one at a time.

This way the components never get destroyed as you switch tabs.

Comment: Is there any better way? I thought i could somehow save the state like React.useMemo (I tried, but it didn't worked). Thanks anyway, it will be my solution for now, but I will still search for another way.

Comment: If you want to preserve your state between page refreshes, that's sort of a different problem. You would have to persist your state data to somewhere outside of react like local storage or the the page URL. There's lot of [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=react+save+state+between+refresh) for that.